# Why is GetHostName replacing some characters with '?'?

Tags: c#, dns

I've noted that ***System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()*** will replace any e.g. Chinese characters in my computer name with '?'. Why is that? It doesn't replace special Swedish characters. 
Worth to note is that ***System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName*** on the other hand doesn't replace my Chinese characters. Why the difference if host names shouldn't contain such characters?
***GetHostAddresses(GetHostName())*** throws an unknown host exception on my machine, ***GetHostAddresses(GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName)*** doesn't.
EDIT:
To clarify the problem I have, our customers might set the computer names to almost anything. Rename PC in Win 10 will only prevent them from using spaces and characters such as []+?-/\ etc. It will not complain when using characters from http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/idn-chars.html (which are supposed to be valid characters in IDN names). It will also not complain if using more than 15 characters (the NETBios constraint).
I know that standard DNS only supports RFC 1123, which permits "A" to "Z", "a" to "z", "0" to "9", and the hyphen (-). But some DNS implementations allow more. E.g. Windows 2000 allows any UTF-8 character. Setting computer name in windows 10 will lead to ***GetHostName*** return that computer name, with some exceptions regarding the type of characters. And that is what I don't understand.
I set my computer name to "Göransθ9876543210" (Swedish ö and Greek theta used and longer than 15 chars) without any objections from the system.
***Environment.MachineName*** returns "GÖRANSθ98765432" as expected (upper case and truncated).
***GetHostName()*** returns "Görans?9876543210". Why replacing theta? Why not replacing ö? Because I'm located in Sweden? But it doesn't replace Norwegian characters either.
***GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName*** returns "Göransθ9876543210".
Interesting to note is that ***GetHostAddresses("Göransθ9876543210")*** returns 6 addresses (2 Ipv4 and 4 Ipv6), ***GetHostAddresses("GÖRANSθ98765432")*** returns 1 (1 Ipv4!?) address and ***GetHostAddresses("Görans?9876543210")*** throws an exception for unknown host. Why does it almost work to use the truncated name, but not at all the name with replaced characters?


Should only ***GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName*** be used to get computer name, or does it have any drawbacks?
Maybe worth to mention that I want to use the computer name in e.g. bonjour and then I don't like it if some characters are replaced by '?'. Especially since bonjour don't allow '?' and will strip it...

Comment: *ALL* .NET Strings are multibyte. Specifically, UTF16. What OS and .NET version are you using?  Windows versions before 2000 didn't support the full UTF16 range. There may be a problem with the DNS entry itself. `?` and `�` are replacement characters used when it's impossible to convert *ASCII* text to another codepage or Unicode due to invalid values, eg saving ASCII text using the wrong codepage.

Comment: Sorry for phrasing it wrong. Of course are they all multibyte. I just meant characters not in the ASCII range and especially Chinese characters which I tested with. I have Win 10 (1607) and using .Net 4. Do you mean it's possible to enter invalid values to my computer name? I just pasted in some Chinese characters found on the web. Interesting to note is that System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()); throws an exception on my system stating that the host is unknown...

Comment: I repeat, that's not the case. People would have noticed, including me. As for the unknow host .. well, what did you expect then? If your *DNS* isn't configured correctly, you'll get into problems. If you want to create DNS entries for testing, modify the `hosts` file.

Comment: *What* are you trying to test? Why type random characters?

Comment: It's the case for me. All I did was using the System settings -> Rename PC function to rename my PC to "GöransLilla人物987654321" and restarted, I dare you to try it out yourself and notice that GetHostName will not return that name, but GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName will. Why the difference? Do one need to do special DNS configuration if you have advanced computer names?

Comment: We have many Chinese customers and they might have named their computers with Chinese characters. That will make our communication code fail. I am trying to figure out how to write code handling such computer names.

Comment: What you do now though, is mistyping computer names. If you google for `Windows Chinese Computer Name` you'll find at least [one case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d8340f54-b96c-4963-81f8-50fe02c1a64f/couldnt-set-computer-name-with-chinese-character?forum=w8itproinstall) where someone failed due to problems in the multilingual *UI*. Try setting the machine name through code. Better yet, set the machine to the Chinese locale first

Comment: The problem is not setting the computer name with Chinese characters. That works, and is allowed. All I'm saying is that if you have customers doing that, then GetHostName will not return that name. At least not unless you change locale as well (haven't tried that since cumbersome for me to get everything in Chinese...).